# Windows safe characters from Linux

Tags: filesystems, windows, ntfs

I've been copying large amounts of files from a Linux backup to a NTFS partition.
The purpose is to have all files accessible from Windows.

From this experience I've learned the following.

1. NTFS appears to support all characters that Ext4 support.
2. Windows does not and will complain in weird ways
3. Windows will delete those annoying files during a full scan and "repair"

I'm looking for a solution that will complain a early and prevent me from writing files on a partition that a windows disc repair would delete.

Is there a way to copy files onto a NTFS partition allowing only file name characters accepted by windows?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150650/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller it looks like detox ["It
     removes spaces and other such annoyances"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/detox.1.html) which isn't acceptable on personal files.

Comment: You could scan your filesystem for problematic names with fslint - which is frely avaliably in the repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using `ntfs-3g` to mount your NTFS filesystem, the [`windows_names` option](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-manual/#4) will prevent files with problematic names from being created:

```
ntfs-3g -o windows_names ...
```