# Why can I not `rsync` certain files between 2 SSD drives?

Tags: filesystems, rsync, ext4

I've recently been migrating the contents from 1 SSD to another via `rsync` and 2 Linux servers:

- Ubuntu 20.0.4.3 LTS running on Raspberry Pi 4 (RPi4)
- Debian 10 running on x864_64 AMD Ryzen 5 2600X Six-Core Processor

**NOTE:** I do not think these details matter but just calling them out for further context.

While attempting to `rsync` the files 99.9% of the files copy without any issue but there are a few that contain special characters such as question marks (`?`).

```
...
rsync: open "/mnt/..... ⭐️/CD 3/05. Have You Ever Seen the Rain?.mp3" failed: Invalid argument (22)

-and-

rsync: open "/mnt/..... 09 Squeeze - Is That Love?.mp3" failed: Invalid argument (22)
...
```

I've tried a number of switches to `rsync` and none have helped with the copying of these particular files. At the moment I'm using this `rsync` command:

```
$ rsync -avz --partial --progress --no-o --no-g \
      --no-perms --inplace --exclude 'lost+found' ubuntu@pi-server:/mnt/* .
```

It appears to be something with the trailing `?` but I'm otherwise stumped by why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR

As it turns out while searching this comment about NTFS-3g made me realize that perhaps I was attempting to `rsync` to a filesystem which might be related to my issue.

*source: [copy filenames with special characters to an external ntfs volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150650/7453)*

> windows_names
> This option prevents files, directories and extended  attributes
> to be created with a name not allowed by windows, either because
> it contains some not  allowed  character  (which  are  the  nine
> characters  "  * / : < > ? \ | and those whose code is less than
> 0x20) or because the  last  character  is  a  space  or  a  dot.
> Existing such files can still be read (and renamed).

#### Inspection Details

Sure enough on inspection I was in fact still using the stock filesystem that came with the external SSD:

```
$ parted /dev/sdg -- print
Model: SanDisk Extreme 55AE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name         Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB               Extreme SSD  msftdata
```

The filesystem I'm copying the files from is however this:

```
$ parted /dev/sda -- print
Model: WD My Passport 262E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      33.6MB  2000GB  2000GB  ext4
```

So to resolve this I'll need to reformat the destination SSD so that it's also an ext4 filesystem.

#### Setting up SSD with EXT4

Before we begin let's use `wipefs` to clear any residual partition & filesystem information that may be lingering on this device. To start we can see it has residual filesystem, `exfat`.

```
$ wipefs /dev/sdg1
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE  UUID      LABEL
sdg1   0x3    exfat 4078-8D8D Extreme SSD
sdg1   0x1c6  atari
sdg1   0x1d2  atari
sdg1   0x1de  atari
sdg1   0x1ea  atari
```

So let's nuke that:

```
$ wipefs --all --force /dev/sdg1
/dev/sdg1: 8 bytes were erased at offset 0x00000003 (exfat): 45 58 46 41 54 20 20 20
/dev/sdg1: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001c6 (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sdg1: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001d2 (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sdg1: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001de (atari): ff ff ff ff
/dev/sdg1: 4 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001ea (atari): ff ff ff ff
```

And now delete the partition:

```
$ parted /dev/sdg rm 1
Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.
```

We're now left with a clean slate:

```
$ parted /dev/sdg -- print
Model: SanDisk Extreme 55AE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  File system  Name  Flags
```

Now let's partition it, put an EXT4 FS on it, and confirm:

```
$ parted -s -a optimal -- /dev/sdg mkpart primary ext4 0% 100%
```

```
$ parted /dev/sdg -- print
Model: SanDisk Extreme 55AE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB               primary
```

```
$ mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdg1
mke2fs 1.44.5 (15-Dec-2018)
Discarding device blocks: done
Creating filesystem with 976745984 4k blocks and 244187136 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 8d030a6a-61fe-4918-9937-0ec02d247006
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
    102400000, 214990848, 512000000, 550731776, 644972544

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (262144 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

Looks better now:

```
$ parted /dev/sdg -- print
Model: SanDisk Extreme 55AE (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdg: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  4001GB  4001GB  ext4         primary
```

To get more of the filesystem space usable with EXT4:

```
### BEFORE
$ df -h | grep -E "File|/dev/sdg1"
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sdg1                 3.6T   89M  3.4T   1% /mnt


### AFTER
$ df -h | grep -E "File|/dev/sdg1"
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg1                 3.6T   89M  3.6T   1% /mnt
```

*source: [Why do I get more free space than ext4 after formatting in XFS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168310/why-do-i-get-more-free-space-than-ext4-after-formatting-in-xfs)*

#### Back to rsync

So with the filesystem properly created as EXT4 and mounted when we attempt to `rsync` the file with the stray `?` within its name it now works without issue:

```
$ rsync -avz --partial --progress --no-o --no-g \
      --no-perms --inplace --exclude 'lost+found' ubuntu@pi-server:/mnt/* .
...
receiving incremental file list
05. Have You Ever Seen the Rain?.mp3
     10,263,388 100%    9.78MB/s    0:00:01 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)

sent 59 bytes  received 10,239,698 bytes  2,925,644.86 bytes/sec
total size is 10,263,388  speedup is 1.00
...
```

#### References

- [How to wipe a signature from a disk device on Linux with wipefs command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-use-wipefs-to-wipe-a-signature-from-disk-on-linux/)
- [Reread partition table without rebooting?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36038/reread-partition-table-without-rebooting)
- [How to Create a New Ext4 File System (Partition) in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/create-new-ext4-file-system-partition-in-linux/)
- [GNU Parted FAQ - archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Parted)
- [mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null) while mounting ext4 fs](https://superuser.com/questions/855547/mounted-filesystem-without-journal-opts-null-while-mounting-ext4-fs)
- [copy filenames with special characters to an external ntfs volume](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/150637/copy-filenames-with-special-characters-to-an-external-ntfs-volume)